# How do applications like SimpleNote automatically update or save user input?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

Applications like SimpleNote, EverNote, etc. automatically save whatever users input, as they go. I'm trying to do the same thing in a simple application. Everything works fine, but it's slow, certainly slower than the applications I just mentioned running on the same machine. (I'm using C#, but everything I'm discussing would probably apply to Delphi, too.)

I have an SQLite database with one table (`comments`) that has two text fields (`name`,`feedback`). One of the fields holds RTF from a rich text box. To enable autosaving I execute this code when the rich text box's `TextChanged` event fires:

```
string sql = @"UPDATE comments SET feedback=@feedback WHERE name=@name";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@name", name));
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@feedback", rtf));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

(`name` and `rtf` are parameters passed to the method; they hold field values. The database connection is created and opened in the object's constructor.)

Should I be executing this code when a different event is fired? ... Is it wrong to keep the database connection open, issuing new commands?

Comment: Fwiw, I doubt a Delphi implementation would look anything like the code in your q.  And in Delphi, you would probably use a more suitable event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here might be that you're saving too frequently. If you save on every keystroke, every typo will also be temporarily saved to the database.

A common pattern is to wait until the user is idle for some time.
This is some pseudo code on how to do that:

```
Timer _timer;

public void Handle_TextChanged()
{
    // If timer does not exist, create it

    // Start or reset the timer to 0 and let if fire in X seconds (3 for example)
    // This prevents the timer from firing for the next 3 seconds
}

public void Timer_Finished()
{
    // When you get here, there hasn't been input for 3 seconds and 
    // you can save to the Database
}
```

Comment: Note that this technique is commonly referred to as debouncing

Comment: Although not very realistic, if the user doesn't give any breaks at all, you'll never save.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz In what situation would a user never stop? I can't imagine a user continuously typing for more than 1 minute. Possible remedies: lower the treshold (eg 1 second) or set a hard limit: either 3 seconds of inactivity or after every x events (100)

Comment: I can't imagine either, but I know I can't imagine everything. I'd go for a maximum non-idle time, i.e. hard limit..

Comment: Worked great; thank you! I ended up using a timer interval of 1 second. 3 seconds was a little too long. ... Note, if you're new to timers (like me) don't forget to turn AutoReset property off (false).